# Print a groupby object for a specific group/groups only

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I need to print the result of groupby object in Python for a specific group/groups only.

Below is the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID'    : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                   'Entry' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
print("\n df = \n",df)
```

In order to group the dataferame by ID and print the result I used these codes:

```
grouped_by_unit = df.groupby(by="ID")
print("\n", grouped_by_unit.apply(print))
```

Can somebody please let me know below two things:

1. How can I print the data frame grouped by 'ID=1' only?
   I need to get the below output:

[image]

2. Likewise, how can I print the data frame grouped by 'ID=1' and 'ID=4' together?
   I need to get the below output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the groups for example with for-loop:

```py
grouped_by_unit = df.groupby(by="ID")

for id_, g in grouped_by_unit:
    if id_ == 1 or id_ == 4:
        print(g)
        print()
```

Prints:

```
   ID  Entry
0   1      1
1   1      2
2   1      3
3   1      4

    ID  Entry
12   4      1
13   4      2
14   4      3
15   4      4
16   4      5
17   4      6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_group` function:

```
df.groupby(by="ID").get_group(1)
```

which prints

```
   ID  Entry
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   1   4
```

You can use the same method to print the group for the key `4`.